# Php Arrays to JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json

i try to make a json output like this:

```
{
    "ergebnis": {
        "kurse": [
            "8b",
            "10m"
        ],
        "test": [
            "abc",
            "dss"
        ]
    }
}
```

but it should looks like :

```
"ergebnis": [
        {
            "kurse": 8b,
            "test": "abc",

        },
        {
            "kurse": 10m,
            "test": "dss",

        }
    ]
}
```

This is my code:

```
$kurse = array();
$kurse[0] = "8b";
$kurse[1] = "10m";
$test = array();
$test[0] = "abc";
$test[1] = "dss";

$ausgabe = array(
    'ergebnis' =>
        array('kurse' => $kurse,'test' => $test)

    );
```

What do I wrong ?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You are setting the *entire* `$kurse` array as the `'kurse'` value.  If you want the 2nd output, then you need to format your PHP array correctly.

Comment: Are you trying to render the second example? The second is invalid JSON. You're missing the opening brace `{` before `ergebnis`. You're also missing double quotes `"` around `8b` and `10m`...

Comment: @RocketHazmat has you covered. His answer works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the *entire* `$kurse` array as the `'kurse'` value.  If you want the 2nd output, then you need to format your PHP array correctly.  As shown, your PHP code creates the JSON shown in the 1st example.

If you want the 2nd example, then you need to do something like this:

```
$ausgabe = array_map(function($a, $b){
    return array(
        'kurse' => $a,
        'test' => $b
    );
}, $kurse, $test);
```

Comment: Thanks. This is THE SOLUTION. (Y)

Answer (score 0):

Use [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

```
echo json_encode($ausgabe);
```

Comment: Oh sorry this is Not the whole Code. It is already in the sourcecode.

Comment: That does not answer the question, but the title is indeed misleading.